# How can I disable Android USB debugging through device admin programmatically

Tags: android, device-admin, usb-debugging

when you become Device admin how to disable USB Debuting option through device admin i need to this pragmatically.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community Become a device admin i just disabled/enabled developer option is it possible we could do that "?